# Django: setting a max number of unique fields in a Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django 1.2. I would like to make a model with 3 fields, as shown below:

```
class Also_Viewed(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    also_page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('page', 'also_page')
```

However for each unique page field, I want to limit the number of rows in the table to a maximum amount (to say 24).

So for example the following types of rows would be okay...

```
(Page_A, Page_x, 3)
(Page_A, Page_y, 21)
...
(Page_A, Page_z, 45)
```

...for up to 24 occurances in the table.

How would you recommend setting this constraint in the Django models.py file?

The only way I can think of is adding another field, and setting the choices option to an iterable of only 24 tuples. This feels like a hack but is it actually a valid solution? Or can you think of more elegant and efficient solutions?

I would also like to ensure that page and also_page are different objects. However I don't know how to approach this one.

Thank you very much for your help, it is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using your own views, you can use model validation as a place to put this code. (but remember you have to call clean yourself)
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

If you want this enforced in the admin, you'll need to override the admin forms.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin

```
# pseudocode. If you went the route of admin forms, 
# the ModelForms would use self.cleaned_data[attr]

if self.page == self.also_page: 
    raise models(or forms).ValidationError("Pages are the same")

elif Also_Viewed.objects.filter(page=self.page).count() >= 24:
    raise models(or forms).ValidationError("Can not have more than 24 items for %s" % self.page)

# let the unique_together catch uniqueness.
```